# Coalesce values from two rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This is the DDL for table `Employee`:

```
create table Employee
(
    EmpId varchar(8),
    StartDate date,
    EndDate date,
    CONSTRAINT pk_EmpId PRIMARY KEY(EmpId)
)
```

Due to data entry error, every EmpId has two rows: one with the EmpId and another one with EmpId with *"-A*" at the end. But both are valid EmpIds.

```
EmpId              StartDate    EndDate
JS123              3/25/2016    4/1/2023
JS123-A            NULL         NULL
BM829              1/5/2018     4/6/2022
BM829-A            NULL         NULL
```

And our view looks like this:

```
create view vwEmployee
as

select
EmpId,
StartDate,
EndDate
from dbo.Employee
```

If I `select * From vwEmployee where EmpId = 'JS123'` I'll get the correct `StartDate` and `EndDate`, which is the expected behavior.

But if I `select * From vwEmployee where EmpId = 'JS123-A'` it'll return the row with the null values in the dates.

How can I coalesce these two columns so that `select * From vwEmployee where EmpId = 'JS123-A'` returns the `StartDate` and `EndDate` for *JS123*?

Comment: What if there are 2 (or more) rows for a EmpID prefix with a non-`NULL` value? Also, really, your prefix and suffix should be 2 separate columns; it would make the solution easier.

Comment: Also, are you *really* storing dates as a string based data type like your sample data implies?

Comment: @ThomA: I've included the DDL. EMpId is PK so there won't be any repeated empids. So it will always be the original EmpId (JS123) and JS123-A.

Comment: The date values are stored in Date columns.

Comment: That isn't what I'm asking. What if `'JS123'` and `'JS123-B;` have non-`NULL` values and `JS123-A` and `JS123-C` don't? None that changes my point that `'JS123' and `A` should be in separate columns too.

Comment: @ThomA, in the question I specified that each empid has _two_ rows. If there were a JS123-B, then I would've mentioned it.

Comment: Why not just remove the bad employees

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this, you can modify your view to join the table to itself on the EmpId column, where the second instance of the table has '-A' appended to the EmpId. You can then use the COALESCE function to return the first non-null value for StartDate and EndDate.

```
CREATE VIEW vwEmployee AS
SELECT
    e1.EmpId,
    COALESCE(e1.StartDate, e2.StartDate) AS StartDate,
    COALESCE(e1.EndDate, e2.EndDate) AS EndDate
FROM dbo.Employee e1
LEFT JOIN dbo.Employee e2
ON e1.EmpId = CONCAT(e2.EmpId, '-A')
```

In this view, when you query for 'JS123-A', it will return the StartDate and EndDate for 'JS123' if the dates for 'JS123-A' are NULL.

Comment: What about if the value is `JS123-B`? Though, to be honest, this smells of GPT.

Comment: In the question I clarified that each EmpId has the original EmpId and another row with the "-A" at the end.

Answer (score 0):

If you split the suffix and prefix into appropriate columns, then you can use a windowed `MAX` on the prefix:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.Employee(EmpIdPrefix varchar(8) NOT NULL,
                          EmpIdSuffix char(1) NULL,
                          EmpId AS CONCAT_WS('-',EmpIdPrefix, EmpIdSuffix),
                          StartDate date NULL,
                          EndDate date NULL,
                          CONSTRAINT pk_EmpId PRIMARY KEY(EmpId));
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.Employee (EmpIdPrefix, EmpIdSuffix, StartDate, EndDate)
VALUES ('JS123',NULL,TRY_CONVERT(date,'3/25/2016',101),TRY_CONVERT(date,'4/1/2023',101)),
       ('JS123','A',TRY_CONVERT(date,'NULL     ',101),TRY_CONVERT(date,'NULL',101)),
       ('BM829',NULL,TRY_CONVERT(date,'1/5/2018 ',101),TRY_CONVERT(date,'4/6/2022',101)),
       ('BM829','A',TRY_CONVERT(date,'NULL     ',101),TRY_CONVERT(date,'NULL',101)),
       ('AB456',NULL,'20230101','20230501'),
       ('AB456','A','20230312','20230604');

GO

CREATE VIEW dbo.vwEmployee AS
    SELECT EmpId,
           ISNULL(StartDate,MAX(StartDate) OVER (PARTITION BY EmpIdPrefix)) AS StartDate,
           ISNULL(EndDate,MAX(EndDate) OVER (PARTITION BY EmpIdPrefix)) AS EndDate
    FROM dbo.Employee;
GO

SELECT *
FROM dbo.vwEmployee;
GO
DROP VIEW dbo.vwEmployee;
DROP TABLE dbo.Employee;
```